# How to add qpdf module in qt 5.10

Tags: qt, pdf, reader, qpdf

I want to add pdfreader in my qt application.when searched online I got to know about qtpdf class.
I try to include same in my project. seems  I don't have package in my system itself so it don't allows me to run qmake with qpdf includes.
Is there any way to download qpdf module from internet?
I'm running qt community edition 5.10
Any other alternatives to display pdf files are also welcome..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `QT += pdf` to your qmake project file.

Comment: I added but have no use.. it's saying unknown module "pdf" on qmake. I think I need to download the module somehow but don't know how and from where.

Comment: You may need to install newer Qt, maybe. Why are you stuck with Qt 5.10?

Comment: QtPdf is for example present in my Qt 5.15.2 installation. I however suspect you may need to opt fot QtWebEngine to be installed in order to have QtPdf installed.